Notification icon in the app does not appear on Android 13 or higher
On Android 12 or lower, when I trigger a notification, the icon is displayed correctly, however on Android 13 or higher, it only displays this symbol in place of the icon.


path to my default icon:
const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
What I hope is that the icon appears correctly in the notification.

Might the be the notification can't be themed. Please try to revise a logo which can be themed try iconkitchen to try logos. Thus also serve how can be viewed on mobile.

@ArbiterChil a logo do aplicativo aparece nos menus do android corretamente independente da versão android, no entanto, apenas não aparece nas notificações.

are you using local notifications plugin ?
